# Why doesn't the Grid Fill Tool work on this mesh?

Tags: modeling

I would like to create faces within the selected edges that match the geometry outside. 
In case that is not possible at all using *Grid Fill* Is there another way to do that?

[image] 
[image]

For me it doesn't look too different to the situation shown in the documentation:

[image]
[image]

[.blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/28846)

Comment: Could you upload your .blend? From what I can see, I think grid fill should be working.. As an alternative, you could select the two long edges and bridge them (W+E), then make 5 loop cuts and remove doubles. I'm not sure if that will work perfectly though.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks, I uploaded the .blend, this should become  a test file for 3D printing therefore the mesh shouldn't be messed up by manual fiddling single vertices.

Comment: If you separate the handle section with Y and then try grid fill on it, it works (I'm assuming that the problem has something to do with the faces connected to the boundary). However it doesn't give the expected result, even after tweaking the span and offset parameters.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks, what result did you expect? After separating it behaves exactly as described in the tutorial. I'm happy with that.

Comment: I expected the result that you got, but it behaved all strange for me. I must have done something wrong, I'll investigate more tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gandalf pointed out the area can be *Grid Filled* by:

- Separate <kbd>V</kbd> the selection
- Grid Fill <kbd>Space</kbd>,<kbd>Grid Fill</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> / *Grid Fill*
- Remove Doubles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> / *Remove Doubles*

[image]

Comment: Hm. Not sure why it didn't work for me.. BTW, you can also get to grid fill from the Ctrl+F menu.